# Magento 302 Error on Update cart

Tags: php, apache, magento, shopping-cart, http-status-code-302

I have a draft website http://fazeee3.com

When I add item to the cart it goes correctly. but when I try to update quantity in cart it post the array correctly to the http://fazeee3.com/checkout/cart/updatePost/ but the response of the server is 302 "Temperary unavilable"

Where should this error exist?
.htaccess / CartController / or what?

I tried to die(); at many parts of code in Cart Controller but I have saw that this line (76) is the problem

```
        $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
```

this line is at "_goBack"

Please advice?!!

Comment: SOLVED !!! 
The problem was with language .

Comment: The filter in row 409 was converting quantity to an array of day and time not the actual quantity

Comment: I am having this issue as well, can you please explain how you fixed it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try add to form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```